# Is it possible to color a table cell from the OS X color picker in Pages 5.1?

Tags: pages

See picture. Only cell border and not the cell fill has the option to pick a color from the OS X color picker. Is there any workaround?

[image: Custom pick color table cell pages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is choose a colour from the selection and then you will see a colour selector icon next to it, click it and the standard colour picker will appear..

[image]

odd I know!

Comment: You rock my socks